# UV Scaling/Packing

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, scale

Can someone please explain to me how I keep the scaling of my UV when packing it to fit the UV island. What I mean exactly is. I'm using a wood plank texture from Megascans, when i unwrap the face and apply the texture the planks are very wide & [not thin like downloaded texture]. So I scale up the UV so the planks are thinner but this obviously makes the UV bigger then the island. So how do I keep the scaling and also fit the the UV in the island ?.